# how to know the mapred-site values on amazon emr cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I was running into memory issues and so I looked up the default values of the parameters like:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.java.opts
```

on the Amazon documentation and figured that the default values were low. So, I added a configuration when creating an EMR cluster like this:

```
classification=mapred-site,properties=[mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096,mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=4096,mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3072m]
```

and created the cluster. Now, how do I check if these values are indeed updated or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either of below ways to find out your mapreduce configuration details.

**Method1:**

- Login to EMR's EC2 instance
- Go to mapreduce configuration path(Usually /etc/hadoop/conf)
- Open mapred-site.xml and search for your properties.

**Method2:**

- Go to JobHistory UI(Usually http://history-server-hostname:19888/jobhistory)
- Traverse to Tools->Configuration

**Method3:**

- Hopefully you can also see all your classifications from Amazon EMR console.